# SqlDataReader null exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have SqlDataReader which fills multiple textboxes, but the issue is when they are NULL I get an exception which I dont know how to handle.

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce='" + akce + "' and rocnik='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'", spojeni);
                spojeni.Open();
                SqlDataReader read= command .ExecuteReader();

                if (read.Read())
                {

                s_ub_cen.Text = read.GetDecimal(59).ToString();
                object nulldate = (s_ub_dat.Text = read.IsDBNull(61) ?
                    string.Empty : read.GetDateTime(61).ToShortDateString());
 }
```

Exception: `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data are null.`

I have like 20 Textboxes, is there any easy solution? I would like to leave the textboxes empty when the value is null, everything is working fine for ShortDatString.

I need to figure out how to handle this like when value from DB is NULL:

```
s_ub_cen.Text = precti2.GetDecimal(59).ToString();
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Ouch - SQL injection via concatenation

Comment: What is `precti2` if `read` is already the `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: You check for null on the second column - why not the first?

Comment: I found out that that it would be hard-coding doing this for 20 textboxes. I just wanted to ask whether there exist better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for [`IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx):

```
if(!precti2.IsDBNull(59))
{
    s_ub_cen.Text = precti2.GetDecimal(59).ToString();
}
```

Also, prevent SQL-Injection by using sql-parameters, don't concatenate strings to build the sql query.

Instead of:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce='" + akce + "' and rocnik='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'", spojeni);
```

this:

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce=@akce and rocnik=@rocnik", spojeni))
{
    command.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@akce", akce);
    command.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@rocnik", klientClass.Rocnik());
    // ....
}
```

**Edit**

> is there any solution that would solve this for 20 textboxes ?

In general there is no automatism. You have to provide a sql-parameter for every dynamic input.

However, if you are looking for an elegant way to get a "safe-string" you could use this extension:

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static string GetSafeString(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
            return reader[colIndex].ToString();
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

You use this method in this way:

```
_ub_cen.Text = reader.GetSafeString(59);
```

Comment: Thanks for answers, is there any solution that would solve this for 20 textboxes ? As this should be implemented to each textbox read right?

Comment: @Marek: You have to add a sql-parameter for every dynamic (user-)input , so no, there is no automatism.

Comment: @Marek: Edited my answer to provide a method that may help to shorten your code.